# Are more runs scored in the seventh inning due to the "changeover"?

Tags: baseball, statistics

I have been told that more runs are scored in the seventh inning of baseball games than any other inning.

The reason would be the "changeover." If the starter is still pitching the seventh inning, it's probably his last, he's tired, and will probably give up more runs than in other innings. If a reliever is on the mound, he's probably not one of the two best (these pitch the eighth and ninth).

Is this in fact true?

Comment: @edmastermind29: I changed the question from a source question to a true-false question and wonder if it can be re-opened in its current form.

Comment: I'll reopen it...but note that the answers are now obsolete, unless elaborated upon to answer your question.

Comment: @edmastermind29: Thanks. The (original) answers were fine. I upvoted both and accepted one. Apparently there is a help center for questions. How do I go to it.

Comment: The answer regarding the Elias Sports Bureau does not address the in/validity of your stated theory (outside of saying "look here and you may find your answer" -- but that is an answer to your original question). [Here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/asking) are several help center items regarding asking questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some links that disprove your hypothesis:

[All Innings Are Not Created Equal](http://www.beyondtheboxscore.com/2011/7/3/2255959/all-innings-are-not-created-equal-how-run-scoring-varies-by-inning)

as well as many others:

[2014 MLB Runs by Inning](http://cleanuphitter.com/mlb/stats/mlb_sortable_scoring.php?parse=inningrunsscored)

including in depth analysis:

[RPI Model](https://baseballprospectus.com/images/analytica/rpi_model.pdf)

Another thing to consider is that the 7th inning is usually an inning that you see a reliever, or you continue to see a dominant starter.  In the reliever case, hitters production drops off (most people think it is because you only see that guy for one at bat every once in a while).  In the starter case, to begin the 7th inning the starter would be throwing a pretty solid game (probably a quality start) and it can be hard to say that even with the pitch count rising that he will be less effective.

Comment: I didn't "grow up" with Google and I didn't realize that the above searches could be done. (I'm old enough to personally remember Pirates like Roberto Clemente or Willie Stargell.) But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Notice how the NL scores only .2 less runs than AL.  Certainly the run creation of the DH doesn't out weigh the strategy that it destroys.

Comment: @MarkMonforti Does it take away strategy, yes it does.  I can't stand watching pitchers hit. More runs, or less I'm a DH supporter.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Elias Sports Bureau](http://www.esb.com/). They keep statistics on all sorts of things across several sports.

Comment: Is this a free site? Or maybe a better question is what can I get free, and what do I have to pay for?

Comment: They don't seem to provide much information about how you can access the stats. My best recommendation would be to contact them.

Comment: FYI, the OP has changed his question.